# sh - prevent interpretation of escape sequences in command substitution

Tags: shell, sh

When I run following in sh:

```
myCommand
```

I get:

```
Lorem\nipsum\tdolores
```

However when I run following:

```
x=`myCommand`; echo "$x"
```

I get:

```
Lorem
ipsum       dolores
```

How to prevent sh from interpreting escape sequences when storing command substitution to a variable?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue using the function `myCommand() { echo 'Lorem\nipsum\ndolores'; }`

Comment: Basically I have a file pattern.txt with the content `Lorem\nipsum\tdolores`. To reproduce it, substitute `myCommand` with `cat pattern.txt`

Comment: If `file` contains the literal string `Lorem\nipsum\tdolores`, then the output of `cat file` will be the same as the output of the function, so I still can't reproduce.

Comment: Ok, on Ubuntu it behaves as I describe, however on Arch Linux, it behaves correctly. It seems to me there is a difference in the echo command.

Comment: Yes, `echo` isn't specified by POSIX in a way that clarifies its behavior in this case. Output is completely unspecified if input contains any backslashes at all.

Comment: Please don't use backticks.  Use `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``

Comment: The target has to unfortunately run on an exotic platform, which does not support `$(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe are perfectly permissible, per the POSIX specification of `echo`: Your `sh` is using the XSI-extended form of `echo`, whereas you're accustomed to either the BSD behavior or bash's noncompliant default hybrid (default because bash also has a compliant `echo`, though it's off unless the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options are both set; noncompliant because that default implementation switches behaviors based the presence of a `-e` option, whereas POSIX disallows `echo` from supporting any option other than `-n` -- one of very few cases where the standard prohibits extensions). Quoting from its [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

> #### APPLICATION USAGE
>
> It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems
>   unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are
>   omitted.
>
> The `printf` utility can be used portably to emulate any of the
>   traditional behaviors of the echo utility as follows (assuming that
>   `IFS` has its standard value or is unset):
>
> The historic System V echo and the requirements on XSI implementations
>   in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 are equivalent to:
>
> ```
> printf "%b\n" "$*"
> ```
>
> The BSD echo is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if [ "X$1" = "X-n" ]; then
>     shift
>     printf "%s" "$*"
> else
>     printf "%s\n" "$*"
> fi
> ```
>
> New applications are encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

---

Thus, you should use:

```
x=$(myCommand); printf '%s\n' "$x"
```